# How to measure time taken by websocket to respond

Tags: java, websocket

We are using web sockets in our project and there is a requirement on to evaluate the speed of websocket. How to measure the time taken by websocket to respond

Comment: Post your code so people can give you examples on your specific implementation

Answer (score 0):

Given that I am new in Stack Overflow and I can't write comments, I will try to give you an answer with the info that you posted.

If you go to Google you will find many examples about "How to calculate elapsed" or "execute time in Java". The following examples were extracted from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-calculate-elapsed-execute-time-in-java/)

Date().getTime():

```
long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
//some tasks
long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();

long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;

System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference);
```

System.currentTimeMillis()

```
long lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//some tasks
long lEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;

System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference);
```

System.nanoTime()

```
long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();
//some tasks
long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();

long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime;

System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference/1000000);
```

Full example

```
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeApp {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

    long lStartTime = new Date().getTime(); // start time

    createArray(); // some tasks to eat time

    long lEndTime = new Date().getTime(); // end time

    long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime; // check different

    System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference);

  }

  public static void createArray() {

    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String sArray[] = new String[1000000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
      sArray[i] = "Array " + i;

  }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you!

Comment: Just a tought : I don't like using a Date instance just to recover the epoch time since System provide it. it doesn't cost much more, in ram or for the CPU, but this is not helpful since you need to call for it against one usin the System.

Comment: Good to know other approaches, and considerations. Thanks.